# Detecting if call is on hold in Android

Tags: android

I am working on an App that should detect when Phone Call is placed on hold, all I can find in Android Telephony documentation is 3 states, that is CALL_STATE_RINGING when Phone is ringing, CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK When call is in progress or on Hold or CALL_STATE_IDLE when no call activity exists, but I would like to know, has anyone found out a way around to detect exactly when call is on Hold? I need to do some action only when call is on hold.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29490832/3836513 . Using PreciseCallState you can read when call is put on hold.

Comment: So am guessing its only possible on Android 5.0 and above?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in  Android 5.0 using the The PreciseCallState, You can read call state such as idle,busy and ringing.[GithubCode](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/c5ac15a3e11c03951e269b243674858411204b67)  [PreciseCallStateDetail](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java)

Comment: import android.telephony.DisconnectCause;
   import android.telephony.PreciseCallState;
        import android.telephony.PreciseDataConnectionState;
        import android.telephony.PreciseDisconnectCause; these Imports are not working they cannot be resolved, do I need to download the entire android framework?

Comment: @Chrome Please below link it will give you brief idea http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/08/android-call-state-listener-example.html#.VgjGxrOY7Hw

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a solution to detect the on-hold state **without using PreciseCallState**:

An on-hold state can occur if the phone transitions from OFFHOOK to RINGING and then back to OFFHOOK. This indicates that a new call came in while another call was already active.

Now, to detect whether the user rejected or accepted the new incoming call:

After the state changes from RINGING to OFFHOOK, I check the call log. If a new call appears in the call log with a status of rejected, I know that the user didn't put the active call on hold. If the call log doesn't show a new entry, it means the user has put the active call on hold.

I handle all phone states with a Broadcast Receiver. From the receiver, I run my foreground service class to manage the call logs, make API requests, and perform other operations.