# How to detect that the outgoing call is answered or not?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, call, telephonymanager, android-broadcastreceiver

Can you help me to understand how to detect whether the outgoing call is answered or not ( I need to record call starting from answer till dropping)? I can detect it for incoming calls but not for outgoing. So please help.

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: Checked this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29490832/5515371

Comment: There is no direct api for detecting that when the outgoing call answered, but yes Its possible only in Rooted phones Since Android 5.0 this is possible for system apps. But you need to use the hidden Android API.