# Get the results of phone calling

Tags: java, android

I am using `callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phone))` to call a number.

What is the best way to get a value of the result(i.e. the receiver rejected or not answering)?

Basically, I have an `ArrayList` which includes a series of phone numbers. I want to call the first one and then stop if it succeeds. Otherwise it continues calling the second one, and so on.

Comment: I don't think there is way if you are starting the call from an intent.

Answer (score 2):

For the benefits of all of us, I'll first explain how to call someone from an Android app, and then, how to receive a result.

**Phone Call**

You need to create an intent, to set its URI data as the phone number you need to call and start the activity.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:8195550504"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

**Get result back**

To get informations about incoming and outgoing calls, you need to ask for permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Then, create a TelephonyManager object and start a listener to receive any call informations :

```
TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

TelephonyMgr.listen(new TeleListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

If any changes are detected from a phone call, this function is triggered :

```
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
```

and gives you informations about the incoming number and the phone state.

There are three states :

IDLE (no call incoming), 
   OFFHOOK (line is busy), 
   RINGING (call is incoming).

You could then use a switch statement to react to it :

```
switch (state){
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:                      
       //CALL_STATE_IDLE;
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CALL_STATE_IDLE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       break;

    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
       //CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       break;

    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
       //CALL_STATE_RINGING
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CALL_STATE_RINGING", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;

   default:
        break;
}
```

If you register a RINGING state but not a OFFHOOK, you know that the call was unsuccessful (and you should call the next number in your list). If the OFFHOOK state follow the RINGING one, the call was successful.

Take a look at this link to create an outgoing call logger and read informations about the sent phone call using PRECISE_CALL_STATE :

[Cannot detect when outgoing call is answered in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134331/cannot-detect-when-outgoing-call-is-answered-in-android)

- Tim S. *Stack Overflow*