# How to get event when i am answering outgoing call

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Can you help me to understand how to detect whether the outgoing call is answered or not ( I need to record call starting from answer till dropping)? I can detect it for incoming calls but not for outgoing. So please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TelephonyManager.ActionPhoneStateChanged` to monitor the `TelephonyManager` state, upon receiving `TelephonyManager.ExtraStateIdle` you know when phone radio is now idling (no call in process).

### Inbound & Outbound BroadcastReceiver Example:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Name = "com.sushhangover.OutgoingCallBroadcastReceiver")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionNewOutgoingCall, TelephonyManager.ActionPhoneStateChanged })]
public class OutgoingCallBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        switch (intent.Action)
        {
            case Intent.ActionNewOutgoingCall:
                var outboundPhoneNumber = intent.GetStringExtra(Intent.ExtraPhoneNumber);
                Toast.MakeText(context, $"Started: Outgoing Call to {outboundPhoneNumber}", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.ActionPhoneStateChanged:
                var state = intent.GetStringExtra(TelephonyManager.ExtraState);
                if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraStateIdle)
                    Toast.MakeText(context, "Phone Idle (call ended)", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                else if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraStateOffhook)
                    Toast.MakeText(context, "Phone Off Hook", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                else if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraStateRinging)
                    Toast.MakeText(context, "Phone Ringing", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                else if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraIncomingNumber)
                {
                    var incomingPhoneNumber = intent.GetStringExtra(TelephonyManager.ExtraIncomingNumber);
                    Toast.MakeText(context, $"Incoming Number: {incomingPhoneNumber}", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Make sure you add permissions to `ReadPhoneState` and `ProcessOutgoingCalls` for this example to work.

Comment: thanks. but i want to detect whether the outgoing call is answered. these events is not triggering after i attend the call.

Comment: @PrabhuPrakash You can track from the outbound call state is *starting* to the point that the call ended (*idle*). Accessing that the call is answered is ***only*** available to service apps/rooted phones via reflection on the `PreciseCallState` that added in API 21+

Comment: oh okey.. thank you.. any other options to get this event?

Comment: @PrabhuPrakash No other way that I know of, you can search StackOverflow, Google, etc... but the only broadcast that I know if to get this is within the PreciseCallState: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29490832/4984832

Comment: For me outgoing calls are not triggering here in the line   "case Intent.ActionNewOutgoingCall:"

Comment: @SushiHangover Hi, How can I call this broadcastreciver from my shared code?