# Detect when the outgoing call starts playing ringback tone

Tags: android, android-activity, sip, gsm

I'm trying to detect the state of an outgoing call when it starts playing ringback tone. I have tried various approaches for detecting this state. Here are some of them:

### 1. Using `PhoneStateListener`:

([Cannot detect when outgoing call is answered in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134331/cannot-detect-when-outgoing-call-is-answered-in-android#29490832))

```
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String num) {
        Log.d(CallStatusPlugin.TAG, ">>>state changed" + state);
    }
}
```

But states like `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE`, `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`  doesn't give us those states.

### 2. Using `READ_PRECISE_PHONE_STATE`:

Adding the method to the above same phone state listener

```
public void onPreciseCallStateChanged() {
    Log.d(CallStatusPlugin.TAG, "onPreciseCallStateChanged");
}
```

But as per my research, reading the precise state requires the app must be a system app.

### 3. Using `NotificationListener`:

```
public class CustomNotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

    public static final String TAG = "CallStatusPlugin";

    public CustomNotificationListener() {
        Log.v(TAG, ">>> CustomNotificationListener");
    }

    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.i(TAG, "New Notification");

        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;

        if ("Ongoing call".equals(extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT))) {
            Log.v(TAG, "outgoing call");
        } else if ("Dialing".equals(extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT))) {
            Log.v(TAG, "dialling call");
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't help because the OS doesn't change the notification when the ringback tone starts playing for an outgoing call.

### 4. Using `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class CallBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String TAG = "CallStatusPlugin";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        Log.i(TAG, "CallBroadcastReceiver state: " + state);

        // TelephonyManager.EXTRA_FOREGROUND_CALL_STATE = "foreground_state"
        Log.d(TAG, "new state >>>>" + intent.getIntExtra("foreground_state", -2));
    }
}
```

But didn't help either.

### 5. Using reflections:

I also tried getting the instance of default dialer using reflection without success:

```
    //com.samsung.android.incallui
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.samsung.android.contacts", new SubTypesScanner(false));

    final ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    ClassLoader[] loaders = { classLoader };

    ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = (ConfigurationBuilder) reflections.getConfiguration();
    configurationBuilder.setClassLoaders(loaders);

    Log.d(TAG, "cl" + classLoader.toString());
    Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "allclasses" + allClasses.toString());
```

I could not get any class (maybe I'm not using the reflection properly)

### 6. Using [`InCallService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService):

By replacing a default dialer (which I don't want to use) with the custom dialer to get the `Call` states.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telecom.Call;
import android.telecom.InCallService;
import android.util.Log;

public class CustomInCallService extends InCallService {

    public static final String TAG = "CallStatusPlugin";

    @Override
    public void onCallAdded(Call call) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCallAdded: " + call.getState());

        call.registerCallback(
                new Call.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionEvent (Call call, String event, Bundle extras) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Call.Callback.onConnectionEvent: " + event + ", " + call.getState());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStateChanged (Call call, int state) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Call.Callback.onStateChanged: " + state + ", " + call.getState());
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

The `onStateChanged` finally gives me something as:

**Call State** -> 9 (`STATE_CONNECTING`) -> 1 (`STATE_DIALING`) -> 4 (`STATE_ACTIVE`)(when answered) -> 7 (`STATE_DISCONNECTING`)

But the call state is also changed to `STATE_DIALING` when there is some problem with the outgoing call like the dialed number is unreachable or the phone is switched off. So this means we can't say `DIALING` state is the state where the outgoing call starts playing the ringback tone.

### 7. Using [`CallManager`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/04b0216/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/CallManager.java) from reflection:

(**Added 3rd Aug 2018**)

```
public class OutCallLogger extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String TAG = "CallStatusPlugin";

    public OutCallLogger() {
        Log.e(TAG, "\n\n\nOutCallLogger Instance Created\n\n\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        Log.i(TAG, "OutCallLogger state: " + state);

        String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Log.i(TAG, "Outgoing Number: " + number);

        // TelephonyManager.EXTRA_FOREGROUND_CALL_STATE = "foreground_state"
        Log.d(TAG, "new state >>>>" + intent.getIntExtra("foreground_state", -2));
        Log.d(TAG, "new state >>>>" + intent.getIntExtra("ringing_state", -2));
        Log.d(TAG, "new state >>>>" + intent.getIntExtra("background_state", -2));
        Log.d(TAG, "new state >>>>" + intent.getIntExtra("disconnect_cause", -2));

        final ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

        try {
            Class<?> callManagerClass = classLoader.loadClass("com.android.internal.telephony.CallManager");
            Log.e(TAG, "CallManager: Class loaded " + callManagerClass.toString());

            Method[] methods = callManagerClass.getDeclaredMethods();
            for (Method m : methods) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Methods: " + m.getName());
            }

            Method getInstanceMethod = callManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("getInstance");
            getInstanceMethod.setAccessible(true);
            Log.e(TAG, "CallManager: Method loaded " + getInstanceMethod.getName());

            Object callManagerObject = getInstanceMethod.invoke(null);
            Log.e(TAG, "CallManager: Object loaded " + callManagerObject.getClass().getName());

            Method getAllPhonesMethod = callManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("getAllPhones");
            Log.e(TAG, "CallManager: Method loaded " + getAllPhonesMethod.getName());

            Method getForegroundCallsMethod = callManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("getForegroundCalls");
            Log.e(TAG, "CallManager: Method loaded " + getForegroundCallsMethod.getName());
            List foregroundCalls = (List) getForegroundCallsMethod.invoke(callManagerObject);
            Log.e(TAG, "Foreground calls: " + foregroundCalls + ", " + foregroundCalls.size());

            Method getBackgroundCallsMethod = callManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("getBackgroundCalls");
            Log.e(TAG, "CallManager: Method loaded " + getForegroundCallsMethod.getName());
            List backgroundCalls = (List) getBackgroundCallsMethod.invoke(callManagerObject);
            Log.e(TAG, "Background calls: " + backgroundCalls + ", " + backgroundCalls.size());

            Timer timer = new Timer();

            // keep printing all the for 20 seconds to check if we got one
            TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
                long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // cancel the timer after 20 seconds
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - t0 > 20 * 1000) {
                        cancel();
                        return;
                    }

                    try {
                        List phonesObject = (List) getAllPhonesMethod.invoke(callManagerObject);
                        Log.e(TAG, "All phones " + phonesObject + ", " + phonesObject.size());

                        List foregroundCalls = (List) getForegroundCallsMethod.invoke(callManagerObject);
                        Log.e(TAG, "Foreground calls: " + foregroundCalls + ", " + foregroundCalls.size());

                        Object backgroundCalls = getBackgroundCallsMethod.invoke(callManagerObject);
                        Log.e(TAG, "Background calls: " + backgroundCalls);

                        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                        Log.i(TAG, "New state: " + state);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, ">>>1. " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            };

            timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 1000); //execute in every 1000 ms
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, ">>>2. " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, ">>>3. " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, ">>>4. " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, ">>>5. " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting all the background/foreground calls & phones as emty results:

```
08-03 15:19:22.638  2586  4636 E CallStatusPlugin: All phones [], 0
08-03 15:19:22.639  2586  4636 E CallStatusPlugin: Foreground calls: [], 0
08-03 15:19:22.639  2586  4636 E CallStatusPlugin: Background calls: []
```

Not sure if OS is using the `CallManager` or not.

**After 2-3 weeks of research, I learned:**

1. Hidden API's are something which provides us the deeper integration with OS (but [Google may remove access to hidden API in Android P](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-undocumented-hidden-apis-android-p/))
2. `Ringing sound of an outgoing call == Ringback tone`
3. `State dialing !== State of playing ringback tone`
4. But **I didn't reach a conclusion where I can say that this is the way where we can get the state on which an outgoing call starts playing ringback tone**

I kept debugging by reading all the OS logs by `adb logcat '*:V'` and saw that a log is being printed at the time when I hear the ringback tone (`adb logcat -b system '*:V'`):

```
07-31 13:34:13.487  3738 29960 I Telephony: AsyncConnectTonePlayer : play
07-31 13:34:13.784  3273  7999 D SSRM:p  : SIOP:: AP = 330, PST = 313 (W:26), BAT = 294, USB = 0, CHG = 0
07-31 13:34:13.902  3738 29960 I Telephony: AsyncConnectTonePlayer : onCompletion
07-31 13:34:14.304  3273 15438 D CustomFrequencyManagerService: releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1352000  uid : 1000  pid : 3273  tag : com.samsung.android.incallui@2
07-31 13:34:14.639  3273  7999 D AudioService: getStreamVolume 0 index 10
07-31 13:34:16.449  4175  4175 D io_stats: !@ 179,0 r 264349 9232882 w 465999 10111332 d 42634 3418440 f 235485 235449 iot 468730 459107 th 51200 0 0 pt 0 inp 0 0 104823.814
```

Then I started googling for something related to **io stats events android** & **gsm connection events** but I'm not able to figure out any way to get that particular state of an outgoing call where the call starts playing ringback tone.

I looked at various Android codes to find out some hints:

1. [`TelephonyConnection`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Telephony/+/master/src/com/android/services/telephony/TelephonyConnection.java)
2. [`GsmConnection`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/jb-mr2-dev/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/gsm/GsmConnection.java)

Any hints or direction where I should look to achieve this? Like GSM connection, [`ConnectionService`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/telecomm/java/android/telecom/ConnectionService.java), [`ConnectivityManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager), [`ConnectionService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService) or [`ConnectionRequest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionRequest) anything?

### Edit 1:

Reading more logs led me to [SipManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html) and I read about [SIP Basic Call Flow Examples](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3665) which I think, Android uses for making or receiving the calls.

```
07-31 16:29:55.335  4076  5081 I reSIProcate: INFO | RESIP:TRANSACTION | TuSelector.cxx:131 | Start add(alm)
07-31 16:29:55.335  4076  5081 I reSIProcate: INFO | RESIP:TRANSACTION | TuSelector.cxx:138 | AlarmMsg is not null
07-31 16:29:55.335  4076  5081 I reSIProcate: INFO | RESIP:TRANSACTION | TuSelector.cxx:140 | Sending AlarmMessage 0 to TUs
07-31 16:29:55.335  4076  5081 I reSIProcate: INFO | RESIP:TRANSACTION | TuSelector.cxx:145 | End add(alm)
07-31 16:29:55.335  4076  5081 I reSIProcate: INFO | RESIP:DNS | DnsResult.cxx:240 | Whitelisting 2405:200:380:1581::42(28): 2405:200:380:1581::42
07-31 16:29:55.335  4076  5081 I reSIProcate: INFO | RESIP:DNS | RRVip.cxx:128 | updating an existing vip: 2405:200:380:1581::42 with 2405:200:380:1581::42
07-31 16:29:55.335  4076  5081 I reSIProcate: INFO | RESIP:TRANSACTION | TuSelector.cxx:71 | Send to TU: TU: CALL-SESSION(8) size=0 
07-31 16:29:55.335  4076  5081 I reSIProcate: 
07-31 16:29:55.335  4076  5081 I reSIProcate: SipResp: 180 tid=935e2afa889bdcad cseq=1 INVITE contact=xxxx@10.56.68.219:5070 / 1 from(wire)
07-31 16:29:55.336  4076  5081 D StackIF : readMessage: messageType 2 tid 0 pduLength 920
07-31 16:29:55.336  4076  5081 D SECIMSJ[0]: [UNSL]< NOTIFY_SIP_MESSAGE
07-31 16:29:55.336  4076  5081 D StackIF[0]: processNotify: id NOTIFY_SIP_MESSAGE
07-31 16:29:55.340  4076  5081 D SIPMSG[0]: [<--] SIP/2.0 180 Ringing [CSeq: 1 INVITE]
07-31 16:29:55.340  4076  4896 D ResipRawSipHandler: handleMessage: event: 100
07-31 16:29:55.340  4076  5082 D OpenApiServiceModule: handleMessage: what 100
07-31 16:29:55.341  4076  4896 D ResipVolteHandler: handleMessage: evt 114
07-31 16:29:55.341  4076  5081 D CpAudioEngineClient: SAE_NotiInfo: SAE_NotiInfo string: 16:29:55.341<180 Ringing:1 INVITE
07-31 16:29:55.341  4076  5081 D VoIpEngineProxy: NotiInfo:Sending IPC_IMS_INFO Noti
```

Will that be of use?

Answer (score 0):

Now in Android R, we have the permission for public api.

```
READ_PRECISE_PHONE_STATE
```

> Allows read only access to precise phone state. Allows reading of detailed information about phone state for special-use applications such as dialers, carrier applications, or ims applications.

Maybe you can use it right now for the precise phone call state,I have got the precise phone call state in custom Android system.

Comment: That's really nice. Thanks for the update, man! I'll keep this in mind and will look into it when I get to it.

Comment: THIS STATEMENT IS FALSE IT IS NOT PUTLIC.

Comment: You cannot use this Permission unless you are the Phone Manufacturer.

Comment: @yams Hey Bro. I just said "Maybe", this is a method for reference, most of the time,  you must have high permission if you want to acess the precise phone call state. This is easier for custom Android system.

Comment: @ifeegoo this is not a correct statement, maybe's don't work.